# How do I get this Arrow icon in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

It' used to send messages, for instance in the Outlook and Skype UWP apps, but I'm unable to find the code to get it using either a `SymbolIcon` or `FontIcon`

[image]

Comment: You mean [this symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol)(E122)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this:

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
      Glyph="&#xE122;"
      />
```